# Database - conceptual model design

Tags: database-design, relational-database, conceptual-model

**We have a task to model following situation using conceptual ERD model:**
We have teachers and students. Students belong into groups. The teachers can teach different lessons/courses, while a course can be taught by different teacher. Each group has its own timetable. And the timetable determines the room & course and the teacher giving the lesson.

The tool used to create the conceptual ERD model is Oracle Data Modeler (although this doesn't matter much in my opinion).

**The task description is a bit vague, so I've added few more definitions:**
The timetable consists of days: Mo - Fri (possibly up to Sunday) and says, which day and time a lesson takes place and who gives the lessons.
Another point is, a teacher can have "expertise" in teaching different lessons, but this doesn't necessarily mean he will be giving lessons for some course. This is also puzzling me how to reflect this in the model and not duplicate the entities etc.

So I was thinking to add days/hours to the timetable, but then a day would be multiple value attribute, which is not allowed in relational model what I understand.

I'm including the current state of my conceptual model.

I've created part of the conceptual model, however I've got stuck with the design and I'm not sure how to continue from logical point of view. Model is attached as picture (don't know how to export the model from ODM into some "source-code").

[image]

May I ask you for your insight how you would model the situation? No need to include complete models, verbal explanation is sufficient.

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not links, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained.

Comment: Give name & edition of your published academic textbook on information modeling & DB design & ask one specific question re just relevant parts in the first place you are stuck. (Manuals for tools to record designs are not manuals on design). We don't know which method you are following until you give a reference. True ER has boxes/tables for entity types, diamonds/tables for relation(ship)s/associations & lines for participations/FKs. Your lines seem like relation(ship)s/associations on entities per some pseudo-ER & ORM methods. PS Relations & FKs have any arity. ER & ORMs pervert that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. I'm not using any textbook, publication etc. The task is simple, model defined situation with a Conceptual ERD model in first step. In next step, create a logical ERD model based on the conceptual one. This is nicely described here so we are talking about the same topic:
https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/3563/3564/85378_conceptual,l.html

Comment: See my previous comments. PS Please clarify via post edits not comments.

Answer (score 0):

When I read your first paragraph, I came up with something very close to yours, except the section that handles the timetable.  IMHO you do not need the Timetable and Monday tables.  Link the group directly to the TimeFrame.

I think you are confusing tables with lines for Timetable / TimeFrame.  No need for a table called TimeFrame_8:00-8:45.  There should be only a Timetable (between Room and Teacher in your diagram) which contains:

- Start date-time
- End date-time
- Room ID
- Teacher ID
- Lesson ID
- Group ID

Your idea of linking Teacher with Lesson to specify the qualifications of the teacher is good.  Your application will need to verify that this link exists before assigning a teacher to a timeframe.

**Disclaimer**: my response is from the point of view of a developer / implementer, not an academic database expert.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is actually what I was looking for! When I was on college, I had a basic intro into databases. Now, several years later I still don't know how to grasp databases correctly. I'll try to update the model for further discussions. :-)